# data messed up when I imported the CSV file

Tags: r

When I imported my csv file to Rstudio, it messed up.
I can't upload pictures, so the link below is the pictures.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FYjGArelMFnCz5Bkeq0vr3sFFL2oLkcT/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aZnZfcWvzRK_gv6dlLha-A1G46k6Ic39/view?usp=sharing

```
library(tidyverse)
absenteeism = read_csv("/Users/angela/Desktop/Absenteeism_at_work.csv")
```

Comment: Can you explain in what way it messed up?

Comment: It looks like your CSV file is `;` separated instead of `,`. try the proposed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
absenteeism <- read_delim("Absenteeism_at_work.csv", delim = ";")
```